# dependent parameter does not refresh after first parameter is input

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

My SSRS report (2008 version) has two parameters. The first is a textbox receiving input for Supervisor' userid. The second is a drop-down which depends on the first parameter to show the all the staff name working under the supervisor. My questions is how the second parameter can refresh automatically after I input the first parameter in the textbox. Do I need a hidden parameter?

Comment: Are you using multi value parameters? What data types? Share the queries you are using to populate both parameters. Delete the dependent parameter and check if the independent one is being populated with the correct data.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am using single value parameter. The data type is varchar. There is no query for first parameter because it gets User ID input from a supervisor. The first parameter is a textbox not a drop down. My second parameter depends on the input value of the first parameter to show all the staff name working under the supervisor. The sql for second paramenter is as follows:

Comment: SELECT distinct Staff_Name
,a.[Network_ID] AS Staff_ID
,a2.Network_ID as [Manager_ID]
FROM ADPFile a 
inner JOIN ADPFile a2 ON a2.Position_NBR=a.Supervisor_Position_NBR
WHERE a2.Network_ID =@User_ID

Comment: You have to set a default value for independent parameter then look for independent parameter `properties parameter report` advanced tab and select `Always refresh`. It's possible user have to click twice in the dependent parameter dropdown list while the refresh is triggered.

Comment: I can not set a default value for the first parameter because it is User ID input by a supervisor. After I input User ID for first parameter, the second parameter does not show 'select a value' drop down list.

Comment: If you set default value for independent parameter the user can still input text and then refresh the dependent parameter. Just set it to something even if it doesn't match with your second parameter dataset. User will delete that default value and put a real value so the dependent parameter will be populated.

Answer (score 1):

In parameter window go to advanced mode and select auto refresh always

Answer (score 0):

In parameter properties for your first parameter, go to advanced properties an select always refresh.
Make sure that your first parameter name is the same as the @user_id used for your second parameter.
The first parameter doesn't need a default.

Comment: If this answer worked for you, can you go ahead and give it a checkmark? It helps build reputation, and will help you get to a position where you can embed images, etc.